# Inform another thread, that an operation is running or finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have multi-threaded application, where different threads may want to perform an operation. I tried to use Mutex to make sure, that thread does not start an operation if it is already running.

```
System.Threading.Mutex mutex;
bool isRunning = System.Threading.Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name, out mutex);
if (!isRunning)
{
   RunMethod();
}
```

within method I created mutex, and try to release it at the end:

```
var mutex = new Mutex(true, name);
try{   
    //do stuff, it takes some time
}
finally
{
    //TODO: I want to get rid of Mutex here
}
```

How do I get rid of mutex? Because even after I called `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` and `mutex.Close()`, it still exists and can be found. How can I inform that operation is currently running or finished?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest using one of the events: [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `Mutex`.  There's not really enough code here for me to formulate a more formal answer for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Same, like CodingGorilla said, using events is easier.
I hope I understand your question well.

This example shows some events techniques:

- Waiting for a thread has been started.
- The use of waiting on multiple events *(WaitHandle.WaitAny())*
- How to terminate a thread, safe.
- Testing an event state without waiting *(.WaitOne(0))*

**Here is an example:**

```
public class MultiThreadedExample : IDisposable
{
    private Thread _thread;
    private ManualResetEvent _terminatingEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent _runningEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent _threadStartedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public MultiThreadedExample()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(MyThreadMethod);
        _thread.Start();
        _threadStartedEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    private void MyThreadMethod()
    {
        _threadStartedEvent.Set();
        var events = new WaitHandle[] { _terminatingEvent, _runningEvent };

        while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(events) != 0)  // <- WaitAny returns index within the array of the event that was Set.
        {
            try
            {
                // do work......
            }
            finally
            {
                // reset the event. so it can be triggered again.
                _runningEvent.Reset();
            }

        }
    }

    public bool TryStartWork()
    {
        // .Set() will return if the event was set.
        return _runningEvent.Set();
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _runningEvent.WaitOne(0); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // break the whileloop
        _terminatingEvent.Set();
        // wait for the thread to terminate.
        _thread.Join();
    }
}
```